# Select rows that fulfill conditions

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I need to write a query that will get a name of the company and shows only 2 rows and after that will check the next company and shows another 2 rows. Let's say that df looks like the one below:

```
x     y     y      name
1      2    3       ammazon
4     5     6       ammazon
7     8     9       ammazon
9     8     7       google
6     5     4       google
3     2     1       google
```

So result should be like that:

```
 x     y     y      name
1      2    3       ammazon
4     5     6       ammazon
9     8     7       google
6     5     4       google
```

I tried to use sql query but couldn't write the correct one. Could you help ? Or perhaps "for loop" would be better solution... anything

Thanks All !

Comment: MySQL I presume? Do you care which 2 rows? Why are there two columns with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `groupby` with `head`

```
df.groupby('name').head(2)

   x  y  y     name
0  1  2  3  ammazon
1  4  5  6  ammazon
3  9  8  7   google
4  6  5  4   google
```